# Dice numbers complemention

Tags: math, logic, discrete-mathematics, dice

I want to program a dice which show me the right numbers like a real one. I know that the added numbers across from each other are 7.
But when I know 4 opposite numbers of the dice, how do I figure out where the two last one belongs?
For example:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spielw%C3%BCrfel#/media/Datei:Craps.jpg

I know that on the top is a 6, and on the left side is 2. How do I know that on the right side is a 4 and not a 3?

Is there a possibility to figure this out without hardcode all possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

Typical dice are "right-handed" (see: [en.wikipedia/Dice#Construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice#Construction)). That is, one way to see it is:

1. Star with a blank cube (whatever way you'll represent it)
2. Pick any face, label it "1"
3. Move to any *adjacent* face, label it "2"
4. Turn 90º in the positive direction

   - positive defined by the [right-hand rule](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korkenzieherregel), meaning rotate *to the left* (yes, confusing, and don't get me started on counter-clockwise... :-))
5. Move forward to the next face, label it "3".
6. Label the remaining faces by the "opposites add to 7" rule

[image: dice schematic]